# Is this phrase grammatically correct -- I have been tempering with the idea that ...?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I thought I have heard of this expression before somewhere a couple of times. If it really means something like "tinkering with the idea"? 
Or maybe I remembered wrong?

Comment: It's not idiomatic.  And "tempering" does not mean "tampering".

Comment: I think you might be confusing it with "tampering with". You wouldn't normally use "tampering" in this sort of sentence, however, as you can see in this sample dictionary definition: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tamper%20with. And you wouldn't use "tempering" either: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temper.   Your use of the expression "tinkering with" is just fine, and means something like, "I've been playing around with the idea."

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the _grammar_ of the phrase, it's just the vocabulary that's wrong.

Comment: "temporising…" would make more sense, but it would still be very odd.